# Pass id parameter to resource in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following method in my Laravel controller:

```
public function specialOffers($id) {
    return \App\Http\Resources\SpecialOfferResource::collection(Offers::all());
}
```

I need some special manipulations, so I've created this SpecialOfferResource resource. The resource code is:

```
class SpecialOfferResource extends Resource {
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request) {

        //here I need the $id passed to the controller's method,
        //but I only have $request

        return [
            //my request fields, everything ok
        ];

    }
}
```

How can I pass $id from the controller's method to this resource? I know I can pass through the request as a field, but is it possible this other way?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't use a collection if you're passing an ID.  You would use a single instance of the resource.

Comment: The same $id is useful to all the items in the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource collection is just a wrapper that formats, or maps, the collection you pass to it.

The collection you are passing is `Offers::all()`, which would include all Offers models.

You'd likely want to use the query builder to narrow down the collection you are passing:

```
public function specialOffers($id) {
    $results = Offers::where('column', $id)->get();
    return \App\Http\Resources\SpecialOfferResource::collection($results);
}
```

Comment: The $id is not a column of the Offer model. I need the $id to make other coding.

Comment: I think you need to make your question more clear with an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I just need the $id inside the resource. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't believe so.  Which is why this is probably an XY problem (asking about your solution and not including the problem itself)

Comment: In the resource I have this code:

`foreach ($this->created_by->items as $item) {
    if ($item->id == $id) {  //here is where I need the $id from the controller's method
        //...
    }
}`

Comment: You could query the items you need before passing them to the resource collection, that's probably the best way to handle it.  The resource classes aren't really designed to handle a lot of logic.

Comment: I know this is another question, but how could I query all the items that satisfy this "if" condition using Eloquent and those nested columns? "where" is for one column, but how can I use it for nested models, like the code above? I'm missing the right way to do it using Eloquent.

Comment: I'd probably isolate this logic to your model instead of your controller or resource, but you can pass conditions to the with() call on Eloquent to eager load the items you need.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: I'm almost there! I'm trying to use "has" for "created_by.items", but the whole item is being returned even when "items" is empty.
$items = Offer::whereHas('special_offer')
            ->with(['created_by.items' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('id', '10');
            }])
            ->has('created_by.items')
            ->get();

Comment: You'll need to use the same callback for with() and whereHas() on created_by.items.  With() loads the items matching the callback, whereHas filters the Offers that have items matching the callback.  So using both is probably what you want

Comment: Could you write it please? I'm trying, but not getting it to work.

Comment: Copy your with, replace with whereHas.  Use both with the same arguments.

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! Handling this logic in the controller is a good quick solution for now. It was a bad idea trying to handle it in the resource as you said. I'll sure think about handling part of the logic in the model, but for now, it's working exactly as I wanted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is acceptable or not, but in some case i do need some parameter passed from controller to use inside toArray resource method and this is what i did.

Create resource class that extend `Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class TestResource extends ResourceCollection
{
   private $id;

   public function __construct($id, $collection)
   {
      parent::__construct($collection);
      $this->id = $id;
   }

   public function toArray($request)
   {
      return [
         'data' => $this->collection,
         'id' => $this->id
      ];
   }
 }
```

And from controller you can call like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Resources\TestResource;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class TestController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
      $id = 30;
      $collection = collect([['name' => 'Norli'], ['name' => 'Hazmey']]);

      return new TestResource($id, $collection);
   }
}
```